# How to exit from a company that is not doing well as a new hire?

Tags: job-change, new-hires

I recently joined a U.S. company (3 months), but there is high turnover in technical roles and high-level posts, and projections are not good for the near future. I have only worked at startups thus far, so my perception prior to joining here was that even though this company is not doing well right now, it will be fine because big companies have a lot of resources to spend, and so can change their fate. I was probably naive.

After being here, it is apparent that things will not get better due to very ingrained, systemic reasons.

How can I justify searching for new jobs at different companies after such a short amount of time? Does this count as a special circumstance since the company is doing so poorly?

Work history: It is 1.5 years earliest position (startup out of money), 1.5 years middle position (startup changed course), 2 years oldest position (startup out of money)

Comment: What is your work history like so far? A short stint can look like a bad pattern or just one random instance of bad luck depending on the rest of your resume.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can explain your reasons and you feel they are justified, then the odd quick move won't affect you.

Obviously too many of them could lead to questions in the future.

It's natural that you will be asked why you are moving so quickly so make sure you have an answer ready when asked.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I justify searching for new jobs at different companies after
>   such a short amount of time? Does this count as a special circumstance
>   since the company is doing so poorly?

There's nothing special here.

You joined yet another startup and decided that this one isn't to your liking. You have decided to leave a little sooner than your past jobs.

I'm guessing you are worried about being labeled a job-hopper and wondering if such a short stint will make you look even more like one.

It probably won't matter much. Your record already shows that you last less than 2 years on average. This short term job will bring your average down, but probably not enough to make much of a difference to a hiring manager. If they would have hired you before, they will hire you now. In the eyes of some hiring managers you already were a job-hopper, and now even more so. Other companies obviously won't care (this one clearly didn't).

Even though your work history is in failed startups, you may want to try and be more careful this time around if you are worried about being a job hopper. Try to reflect on why you didn't understand the circumstances of this company *before* you joined, and how you can prevent that same mistake again in the future.

Work hard to find a new job while you are still employed here. Take your time and try to find some place where you can stick around longer. Get and accept an offer, then resign and work out your notice period.

Comment: Cannot emphasize this piece enough " find a new job *while* you are still employed"